# Modo de execução da Activity

Tags: android

Galera criei uma activity fiz o layout, essa activity vai inserir o valor em um TextView de outro Layout, mas eu queria que ela abrisse como na imagem, alguem sabe como fazer?

[image: img]![img][1]

tbm não sei se é de outra forma sem ser com activity, já fiz com DatePickerDialog deu certo, mas na activity não consegui

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Olá, este componente que abriu como na imagem se chama **AlertDialog**, o dialog padrão pega as fontes e o layout padrão do android, para fazer um Dialog customizado que nem na imagem siga [este roteiro](https://www.devmedia.com.br/android-dialog/26749) da DevMedia. Bem vindo

Comment: muito obrigado...